# java will this threading setup work or what can i be doing wrong

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite

Im a bit unsure and have to get advice.
I have the:

```
public class MyApp extends JFrame{
```

And from there i do;

```
MyServer = new MyServer (this);
MyServer.execute();
```

`MyServer` is a:

```
public class MyServer extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
```

`MyServer` is doing `listen_socket.accept()` in the `doInBackground()`

and on connection it create a new

```
class Connection implements Runnable {
```

I have the belove `DbHelper` that are a singleton.

It holds an Sqlite connection. Im initiating it in the above `MyApp`
and passing references all the way in to my runnable:

```
class Connection implements Runnable {
```

My question is what will happen if there are two simultaneous `read` or `write?
My thought here was the all methods in the singleton are synchronized and
would put all calls in the queue waiting to get a lock on the synchronized method.

Will this work or what can i change?

```
public final class DbHelper {

    private boolean initalized = false;
    private String HomePath = "";
    private File DBFile;

    private static final String SYSTEM_TABLE = "systemtable";   
    Connection con = null;
    private Statement stmt;
    private static final DbHelper instance = new DbHelper ();

    public static DbHelper getInstance() {

        return instance;

    }

    private DbHelper () {

        if (!initalized)
        {
            initDB();

            initalized = true;
        }
    }

    private void initDB()
    {
        DBFile = locateDBFile();
        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            // create a database connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:J:/workspace/workComputer/user_ptpp");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private File locateDBFile()
    {
        File f = null;
        try{
            HomePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println("HomePath: " + HomePath);
            f = new File(HomePath + "/user_ptpp");
            if (f.canRead())
                return f;
            else
            {
                boolean success = f.createNewFile();
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println("File did not exist and was created " + HomePath);
                    // File did not exist and was created
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File already exists " + HomePath);

                    // File already exists

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Maybe try a new directory. " + HomePath);
            //Maybe try a new directory.
        }
        return f;
    }

    public String getHomePath()
    {
        return HomePath;
    }



    public synchronized String getSelectedSystemTableColumn( String column) {

        String query = "select "+ column + " from " + SYSTEM_TABLE ;
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {

                String value = rs.getString(column);

                if(value == null || value == "")
                    return "";
                else
                    return value;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } finally {

        }
        return "";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in `java.sql` are required to be thread-safe, according to the spec:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame9.html

> We require that all operations on all the java.sql objects be
>   multi-thread safe and able to cope correctly with having several
>   threads simultaneously calling the same object. Some drivers may allow
>   more concurrent execution than others. Developers can assume fully
>   concurrent execution; if the driver requires some form of
>   synchronization, it will provide it. The only difference visible to
>   the developer will be that applications will run with reduced
>   concurrency.

This is unlikely to be a good idea.  You ought to reconsider this design.  I think pooling connections and closing them in the narrowest scope possible would be a better idea.

Comment: @Erik, the singleton pattern ensures that only one oject is created, further than that no guarantees are made; concurrency is orthogonal.

Comment: Nope, the Singleton anti-pattern has nothing to do with thread safety.  A mutable, unsynchronized Singleton will be a huge headache.

Comment: what about if i use MySql instead of Sqlite and have this the same setup

Comment: Database vendor makes no difference.

Comment: @duffymo thanks, For now i put java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock on the method critical section. Wanted instead to try the embedded version of   h2database.com for my desktop java app. Me being a noob, what you think?